# Find out everything install changes in my computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, updates

I am going to install few programs on my Windows7, but I wanna know what do those installs change in my computer. For example what registry entries does it create etc. Or what changes does it make in my computer configuration.

Is it possible to observe the updates somehow or later find out? With some proggie perhaps..

Comment: Every program is different.  The current question cannot be given an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound : hmm but anything that would observe all activity in registry? That wouldn't be program specific then...

Comment: possible duplicate of [track change to registry before installing software](http://superuser.com/questions/84244/track-change-to-registry-before-installing-software)

Comment: @Ramhound: [Don't make such assumptions, you can easily tell what a program does](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Answer (score 1):

ProcMon, by Sysinternals. It's a bit of an advanced tool, though, but it can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/installation-monitor.php) claims it can do this. Not free, but has a 30-day fully functional free trial.  Probably worth it if it does what you need.